# mysql : changing root password

Tags: mysql

I mistakenly keyed in

```
<delete from mysql.user where password =''>
```

Unfortunately the password for user is ''.

When I try to use mysqladmin i am getting message that I cannot set password for

```
<root @ localhost>
```

Any ideas???

Many thanks

Comment: How to Reset the Root Password - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Unix-like OS:

> 1. You have to kill the mysql daemon.
> 2. Create a text file and write:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('YOUR_PASSWORD') WHERE User='root';
```

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

> 1. Open a console and type "mysqld_safe --init-file=YOUR_FILE &"
> 2. Restart the server
> 3. Now you should be able to work.

Comment: `ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'password' in 'field list'`

Answer (score 0):

run this command :

```
mysqladmin -u root -p'oldpassword' password newpass
```

Comment: I get the error msg access denied for user 'root' @ 'localhost' <using password no>

Answer (score 0):

If there is no password for you root admin you can just connect without the "-p" option.
Then you can modify the password in the table 'mysql.user'

Comment: Error message access deied for user 'root' @ 'localhost' <using password No>

Comment: Didn't get the fact that you deleted your root account, before ManseUK's edit of your post. All your users where having a '' password? :) Anyway, Ali's answer should do the trick (restarting the daemon with the '--skip-grant-tables' option)

Answer (score 0):

Stop `mysqld` and restart it with the `--skip-grant-tables` option.
Then run in mysql shell:

```
INSERT INTO user
VALUES('localhost','user',PASSWORD('newpass'),
'Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y',
'Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y',
'','','','',0,0,0,0);
```

Logout, and restart mysql in normal mode.

Comment: When I try to use mysql shell, still get message access denied for user root @ localhost using password no

Comment: If you run `mysqld --skip-grant-tables`, it won't ask you for password. Just open shell with `mysql` command.